# Understanding why some functions are not profiled in Gprof?

Tags: c++, profiling, gprof

I am trying to use gprof and the legend reads for the calls column

```
calls      the number of times this function was invoked, if
           this function is profiled, else blank.
```

I have some functions for which that field is missing? What does it mean? I didn't give any special options.

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name 
 68.77      9.38     9.38                             void BilinearForm::int3d...
 27.71     13.16     3.78                             void BilinearForm::int2d...
  1.54     13.37     0.21                             BilinearForm::finalize()
  0.73     13.47     0.10 11275600     0.00     0.00  frame_dummy
...
```

This is how the head looks like.

Comment: inlined functions?

Comment: You're saying that if calls is missing the function has been inlined?

Comment: I think it is a possibility, unsure btw.